# jar execution says -- "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" not found

Tags: jdbc, executable-jar

I have designed a project Database Migration.
While I run it from netbeans directly it executes properly, but when I use its jar - which is created by netbeans - then it gives an exception
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found
pls help me

Comment: Did you copy the required libraries with your executable jar? When you produce the jar in netbeans (which is under the 'dist' folder) there should be a 'libs' folder that must be copied too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the JDBC driver at the path. It is working in Netbeans, because it has configured it for you. Search how to set JDBC driver by downloading it from MySQl.

Answer (score 0):

download the `mysql jdbc driver jar` and copy it the lib folder